# Why does std::bind statically type check arguments passed to the function?

Tags: c++, stdbind

Not exactly a question but more of a musing... I wrote a program to test how 'std::bind' passes arguments to the function being binded. It seems like in this instance the C++ compiler performs static type checking:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void take_int(const int *a)
{
    if (a)
    {
        std::cout << "a is " << *a << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "null" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int *a = new(int);
    *a = 4;
    take_int(NULL); //prints 'null'
    auto fn = std::bind(take_int, NULL); //fails to compile
    fn();
    return 0;
}
```

It seems inconsistent to be able to directly call the function with NULL but for it to fail at compile time when doing so through std::bind.

I guess std::bind is using more modern C++ features which chooses to enforce this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Compiler defines `NULL` as `0` which as a literal can be implicitly converted to an `int*`. Thats why your first call is succesful.
But `std::bind()` will generate an object for `<void (&)(const int *),int>` which can't be called since a variable of type `int` cannot be implicitly converted to `int*`.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you are using `NULL`, which is deprecated. Instead, you should be using `nullptr`.

If you use `nullptr` in your snipped, code compiles as expected.

You need to keep in mind that

> `NULL` can be an integer literal with value zero, or a prvalue of type
>   std::nullptr_t

In your case, it is integer literal. When you call a function with that value, it is converted to pointer - this is why calling a function directly works.

Comment: You say that "When you call a function with that value, it is converted to pointer - this is why calling a function directly works." Is this not what I'm doing with std::bind? I am calling a function with a NULL value. Why is it that in this case NULL is not converted to a pointer?

Comment: @LukePurnell, no, because this implicit conversion to pointer only exists for literal 0. But bind works with types, so it tries to find a function which accepts integer types - and integer types are not implicitly convertible to pointers. This is all a result of this special quirk, of integers not convertible to pointers, except for 0 literal.

Comment: _Is that not what I'm doing with std::bind?_ No - look at the prototype for [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). The types of `Args...` are deduced to be exactly what you passed - it has no way to know you wanted it to apply an implicit conversion as if to `take_int(const int*)`.